# Postgresql not authenticating a user

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I created a user "kylo" in Postgres and granted it superuser right. When I enter the below command its not working:
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are giving wrong password:

Try creating new password for user:`kylo`:

```
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

To set a Role password:

```
ALTER ROLE role_name WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password';
```

> please note : (CREATE USER is the same as CREATE ROLE except that it
>   implies LOGIN.)

*Also, grant privileges to the user/role on a particular DB you wish to log in.*

**EDIT: 1**

Execute this command on cli to change to normal user in you case `kylo`if using Ubuntu/CentOS etc.:

```
sudo -i -u kylo #change to a user which is available to your system
```

Try login to psql, it might work.

Even after this the problem is not solved add an entry to `pg_hba.conf` might be located under /etc/postgresql/9.x/main, If not run this command to know the location `locate pg_hba.conf`

Afterwards, add an entry to the conf

```
local   all   kylo    trust
```

then change the password of user and edit the entry in conf to

```
local   all   kylo    md5
```

> **trust** - anyone who can connect to the server is authorized to access the database
>
> **peer** - use client's operating system user name as database user name to access it.
>
> **md5** - password-base authentication

Comment: Vancleff, still same error. Applied the below commands: postgres=# ALTER USER kylo  WITH PASSWORD 'mypass';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# ALTER ROLE kylo  WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypass';
ALTER ROLE

Comment: In your case I assume you are trying to login to psql as a root user, could you change to your default user and retry.

`sudo -i -u kylo` and retry you psql login command

Comment: Yes. I was issuing command through another OS user, but when I switched to Kylo OS user then it worked.

Comment: @Umar you won't believe, I had reinstalled psql facing this issue a few years back, it reminds me If I would have known that time. :)